# iText | Can't set cell border color

Tags: itext

I am trying to set border colors of table cells. No matter what I try, the border color is not changing - it's always black! What am I doing wrong? Here's my test code. `cell1` should have a red top border and a blue bottom border:

```
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);

    PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell 1"));
    cell1.setBorderColorTop(new BaseColor(255, 0, 0));
    cell1.setBorderColorBottom(BaseColor.BLUE);
    table.addCell(cell1);

    PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell 2"));
    table.addCell(cell2);
```

Comment: Excellent question! I had to look this up myself. I'll create an example to show how it's done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please take a look at the [ColoredBorder](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/cell-borders-without-cell-or-table-events#1618-coloredborder.java) example. I have to admit: there's an inconsistency in iText.

By default, all borders are equal in iText. If you change the color of one border, you have to add an extra line:

```
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell 1"));
cell.setUseVariableBorders(true);
cell.setBorderColorTop(BaseColor.RED);
cell.setBorderColorBottom(BaseColor.BLUE);
```

With the `setUseVariableBorders()` method, we tell iText that the borders aren't equal. As you can see, the colors are now respected:

[image]

Using `setUseVariableBorders()` isn't necessary if you change the width of a border. In that case, the default is change automatically (this is the inconsistency I mentioned earlier):

```
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell 2"));
cell.setBorderWidthLeft(5);
cell.setBorderColorLeft(BaseColor.GREEN);
cell.setBorderWidthTop(8);
cell.setBorderColorTop(BaseColor.YELLOW);
```

As you can see, there are still two black borders in cell 1 and cell 2. We can remove these with the `setBorder()` method:

```
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell 3"));
cell.setUseVariableBorders(true);
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT | Rectangle.BOTTOM);
cell.setBorderColorLeft(BaseColor.RED);
cell.setBorderColorBottom(BaseColor.BLUE);
```

If you look at cell 2, you see that we have chosen rather thick borders. As a result these borders overlap with the text in the cell. We can avoid this with the `setUseBorderPadding()` method:

```
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT | Rectangle.TOP);
cell.setUseBorderPadding(true);
cell.setBorderWidthLeft(5);
cell.setBorderColorLeft(BaseColor.GREEN);
cell.setBorderWidthTop(8);
cell.setBorderColorTop(BaseColor.YELLOW);
```

Now the border will be taken into account when calculating the padding.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response. Your solution works! However, I am finding minor nuances that are preventing me from creating a totally clean output. It appears that when variable borders is **not** set, iText is doing some smart border folding so that there is only a single border between adjacent cells. As soon as I turn on variable borders, I start seeing double and/or overlapping borders of different colors. My use case is a table with grouped rows and columns with black group borders, except the last column in every vertical group to have a LIGHT_GRAY left border.

Comment: Yes, there are only two workaround to avoid this: remove one of the two borders that overlap, or define [customer borders](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-define-different-border-types-single-cell) using [cell events](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/table-events).